# Nunjucks check for object or string

Tags: nunjucks

How can I check if a variable is an object or string in an if block? 
It seems one can not call functions inside the `{% if ... %}` block.
And the other `{{ if() }}` syntax seems only to be for inline conditions.

I solve it now to test for some object properties that should be there when the variable is an object, but there should be a better solution. Like an `isObject` or `isString` function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a [custom filter](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#custom-filters):

```
var env = new nunjucks.Environment();

env.addFilter('is_string', function(obj) {
  return typeof obj == 'string';
});
```

This is what the template would look like:

```
{% if item|is_string %}yes{% endif %}
```

```js
var env = new nunjucks.Environment();

env.addFilter('is_string', function(obj) {
  return typeof obj == 'string';
});

var res = env.renderString("{% if item|is_string %}yes{% endif %}", { item: 'test' });

document.body.innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<script src="https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/files/nunjucks.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Custom filter or maybe you can...

```
if (string(foo) == foo) { // string }
else { // object }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built-in test of a string:

```
{% if foo is string %}
   It is a string
{% endif %}
```

The **is**-keyword marks the condition as a nunjucks/jinja-test. The word **string** refers to the built-in test.

See for tests the jinja-description:

- https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#tests
- https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#builtin-tests

Nunjucks is [inspired by jinja2](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/). I have not found a nunjucks-documentation about tests, but the string test works.